# How to pass data to a Jquery Dialog when it opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-dialog

I am trying to display the Jquery dialog when the JSP loads. I check for a flag from the bean (showPopupFlag), so this is different from user clicking a button on a already loaded page.
I am trying to push some data into the pop when it displays using the dialogContent.
Is this possible to send/push data to the dialog (I know it is) but some how I am missing something. Any help is appreciated. - Thanks

My html code is

```
<div id="dialogId" title="JqueryDialogTest"> 
      <div id="dialogContent"></div>
</div>
```

My included Js is

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $(function(){
                $("#dialogId")                   
                .dialog({autoOpen: false,  modal : true} );

         } );

    }); 

    $(function(){       
     if($("#showPopupFlag").val() === "true") {
                $("#dialogContent").html($("#displaySubjectNotFoundPopup").val()); 
                $("#dialogId").dialog("open");
     }
    });
```

Comment: What is the purpose of "pushing data to the dialog" ? Why not just set the variables you need and then have the dialog use them?

Comment: You need to use data from html page. data passing is not needed.

Comment: How would you use data from html page, yes, the hiddenField on the html is available. Do you have a quick example? remember this popup is NOT driven by clicking a button, I am checking a flag from bean during page load and this is somehow causing race condition.

Comment: The purpose of the dialog is to display an error upon server side validation and use the user entered data on the JSP in the dialog. This is running in a Portlet environment.

Answer (score 0):

You are messing up the auto execute function and the document ready block. So you can do achieve it by :

```
//document ready block
$(document).ready(function () {
       //initialize the dialog ui box
       $("#dialogId").dialog({
                 autoOpen: false,
                 modal: true
             });
     //auto executing function 
    //or you could simply remove the function and let the code block be executed on document ready
    (function(){
         if($("#showPopupFlag").val() == "true") {
                    $("#dialogContent").html("someValue"); 
                    $("#dialogId").dialog("open");
          }
    }());    
    });
```

And here is the demo [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2KpG9/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes hardcoding works, but need to set that data from the bean dynamically using the id in the html #displaySubjectNotFoundPopup which I am pushing to the dialog. That is not showing up.

Comment: check this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2KpG9/4/) ... is this what you need ... ??

Comment: what exactly dynamically refers to ... the content id displaySubjectNotFoundPopup is present on the page right ??

Comment: Yes, that id displaySubjectNotFoundPopup is present and available on the JSP, but not picked up by the dialog. Thanks again.

Comment: Pawal - Thanks for your help, I am able to Push the values correctly. Js, JSP combo in portlet environment is very tricky.